# doesn't have a field "clientMutationId" in Relay mutations

Tags: sql, graphql, relay

when I am trying to update a record in Relay using Relay Mutations I getting an error like this.

> doesn't have a field "clientMutationId"

But I did't declare any clientMutationId in my GraphQL schema. Here  is my code in Relay

```
function updateZipdata1(){
  console.log("update zip");
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;
    var config = {
        userName: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxxx',
        server: 'xxxx', 
        options: {
            database: 'xxxx'

        }
     }
    var results = [];
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', (err)=> {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err);
        }
        var ZipCode="123456";
        var RecNo="789456";

        var sql = "update dbo.xrxZip set ZipCode='"+ZipCode+"' where RecNo='"+RecNo+"'";
        var request = new Request(sql,
            (err, rowCount)=> {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQLError');
                    connection.close();
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                  console.log("sql:"+rowCount)
                    connection.close();
                    resolve(results);   
              }
            });
            request.on('row', (columns)=> {
            var row = {};
            columns.forEach((column)=> {
                if (column.isNull) {
                    row[column.metadata.colName] = null;
                } else {
                    row[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
                }
            });
            console.log("hai:"+results)
            results.push(row);

        });
          connection.execSql(request);
      })
   })
};
```

**my GraphQL schema:**

```
var zipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Zipcode',
  fields: () => ({

    ZipCode: {type: GraphQLString},
    City: {type: GraphQLString},
    ShortCode:{type: GraphQLString},
    State:{type: GraphQLString},
    Phone:{type: GraphQLString},
    TaxCode:{type: GraphQLString},
    Tax:{type: GraphQLString},
    RecNo:{type: GraphQLString}

  }),
});

var zipCodeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Zip',
  fields: () => ({
    zipcodes: {type: new GraphQLList(zipType)},
  }),
});

export var Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Mutation",
     fields: () => ({
      UpdateZipcode:{
        type: zipCodeType,
        args: {
          ZipCode: {type: GraphQLString}
        },
        resolve: (root,{ZipCode}) =>updateZipdata,

      }
    })
  })
})
 const updateZipdata = {
 zipcodes: updateZipdata1(), // Calling the function
};
```

When I run it in terminal for hard coded ZipCode and RecNo it is working without any error. But when I try to execute in Relay I am getting an error like as mentioned above.

**Hear is my Relay code:**

This is subclass in Relay for mutations.

```
export default class updateZipMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    alert("getMutation");
    return Relay.QL`mutation{UpdateZipcode}` ;
  }
  getVariables() {
    alert("getVariables");
    return { RecNo: this.props.data.RecNo,ZipCode:this.props.data.ZipCode,City:this.props.data.City,Phone:this.props.data.Phone,ShortCode:this.props.data.ShortCode,Tax:this.props.data.Tax,TaxCode:this.props.data.TaxCode,State:this.props.data.State};
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    alert("getFatQuery")
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on Zipcode {
          RecNo,
          ZipCode,
          City,
          Phone,
          ShortCode,
          Tax,
          TaxCode,
          State
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    alert("getConfigs");
    return [{
      type: 'zipCodeType',
      fieldIDs:{
        RecNo: this.props.data.RecNo
      },
    }];
  }
}
```

Here is my main class in Relay calling the subclass for mutations:

```
export default class zips extends React.Component {
 Relay.Store.update(
      new updateZipMutation({        //I am getting the data from form
        data: { RecNo, ZipCode,City,Phone,ShortCode,Tax,TaxCode,State},
      })
    );
  }
}
```

any one please give me suggestions how to resolve it, and how to work on mutations. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Relay mutations must have `clientMutationId` field that is accepted in their `input` and is returned as is in the resulting payload. Relay uses them to track which mutation server have response to. In addition for Relay, mutations must accept one argument - `input`. It can be a InputObject type, but it must be formed like that. Here is detailed guide on Relay GraphQL Mutation inteface https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-mutations.html#content

In your case you could do something like this:

```
export var Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Mutation",
     fields: () => ({
      UpdateZipcode:{
        type: zipCodeType,
        args: {
          input: {type: new GraphQLInputObjectType({
            name: "UpdateZipCodeInput",
            fields: {
              clientMutationId: { type: String },
              ZipCode: { type: String },
          })}
        },
        resolve: (root,{input: { clientMutationId, ZipCode}) => ({
          ...updateZipCode(ZipCode),
          clientMutationId,
        }),
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: OMG! This was a "hidden" error behind a very vague error message! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just use Relay helper function from `graphql-relay` package

```
mutationWithClientMutationId
```

It will provide a Relay compatible mutation

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#mutations